# Select n elements of the list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of elements

```
data = {-0.023504, -0.022846, -0.022846, -0.025479, -0.025479, -0.024821,...}
```

The list consists of 20000 elements.

How to select first 10000 of elements?

Comment: Try `data[[;;10000]]`

Comment: Look up [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) in the documentation; its short form is the `[[ ... ]]` operator expression that Bob Hanlon showed you.

Comment: Or alternatively: `Take[data,10000]`